# LINQ for this foreach

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I suspect there is LINQ for this but I cannot figure it out
selectedKeys is a HashSet

```
public IEnumerable<FTSword7bitThesaurus> FTSwordsPlusSelected 
{ 
    get 
    {
        foreach (FTSword7bit w in FTSWords7bit)
        {
            yield return new FTSword7bitThesaurus(this, w, selectedKeys.Contains(w.Key));
        }
        Debug.Write("Done FTSthersarus FTSwordsPlusSelected");
    } 
}
```

Comment: you should try resharper! It helped me learn linq and lambda expressions while i worked

Comment: @Jonesy resharper look nice but this is out of my pocket.

Comment: i believe you can use it 30 days for free

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx)

```
return FTSWords7bit.Select(w=> 
                  new FTSword7bitThesaurus(this, w, 
                                           selectedKeys.Contains(w.Key)));
```

Answer (score 2):

How linq does it need to be?

```
get 
{
    var result = FTSWords7bit
      .Select(x => new FTSword7bitThesaurus(this, x, selectedKeys.Contains(x.Key));
    Debug.Write("Done FTSthersarus FTSwordsPlusSelected");
    return result;
}
```

Comment: You have a transcription error there. You've changed the var to `x` but still using `w.Key`.